# insert node field into sidebar

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to figure out how to have sidebar content for a 'page' content type. I've created a fied in page called sidebar. Now how do I insert that content if it exists into the right sidebar? Would I use  hook_page_alter().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CCK Blocks module](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks) will do it for you: 
Don't be confused with "CCK" in name, Drupal 7 has fields in core so you don't have to install it.

Comment: That looks like a nice module. I figured out how to do this with .tpl.php files. I followed this: http://adaptivethemes.com/page-template-suggestions-per-node-type. Then I took out the sectioning code in the page template and added it into my custom node type template.